# Is there a function to set two mouse buttons to toggle a script?

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I'm working on a recoil script, and I want to be able to activate or toggle it using two mouse buttons at the same time. This is what I have so far. I want to use g4 and g5 to make it work, not just g4

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
  if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
    EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
  elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
    ReleaseMouseButton(2) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
  end
  if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4) then
    recoil = not recoil
    spot = not spot
  end
  if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil) then
    if recoil then
      repeat
        MoveMouseRelative(-2, 5)
        Sleep(10)
        MoveMouseRelative(2, -5)
        Sleep(21)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
  if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
    EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
  elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
    ReleaseMouseButton(2) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
  elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4) then
    if btn_5_is_pressed then
      recoil = not recoil
      spot = not spot
    else
      btn_4_is_pressed = true
    end
  elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5) then
    if btn_4_is_pressed then
      recoil = not recoil
      spot = not spot
    else
      btn_5_is_pressed = true
    end
  elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 4) then
    btn_4_is_pressed = false
  elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 5) then
    btn_5_is_pressed = false
  elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil) then
    if recoil then
      repeat
        MoveMouseRelative(-2, 5)
        Sleep(10)
        MoveMouseRelative(2, -5)
        Sleep(21)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
  end
end
```

---

**EDIT**
Toggle by double-click of mouse button #6:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6 then
      local now = GetRunningTime()
      if now - (prev_time or -1000000) < 200 then
         prev_time = nil
         recoil = not recoil
      else
         prev_time = now
      end
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil then
      repeat
         MoveMouseRelative(-2, 5)
         Sleep(10)
         MoveMouseRelative(2, -5)
         Sleep(21)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
   end
end
```

Comment: can you suggest a code that i have to press g6 two times to toggle the script? “ click g6 two times “ turn on and “ click g6 two times “ turn off? thanks